kernel does not recognize dedicated gpu
I want to use my laptop's dedicated gpu via nvidia-prime or bumblebee, but Ubuntu only recognizes the internal intel graphics chip. The dedicated gpu is a Nvidia GeForce 940MX.
lshw -c display outputs this:
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:139 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

How do I make the dedicated gpu recognized, so I can use it with nvidia-prime?
edit: lspci -nnk | grep -EA3 "3D|VGA" outputs this
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T570 [17aa:2247]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915


edit:
dkms status outputs this:
   nvidia/535.183.01, 6.8.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
   nvidia/535.183.01, 6.8.0-50-generic, x86_64: installed
   nvidia/535.183.01, 6.8.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed



    




I prefer to not open the back of the laptop to not forfeit my guarantee rights

Any settings related to graphic in your uefi menu? cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log please.

unfortunately the output is too long for the character limit, how can I submit the log for you?

Also no graphic settings in bios

You could use https://pastebin.com/ for sharing the log. Also dmesg logs might help.

link Here is the log in pastebin @tl-photography.at

No trace of nvidia lspci -nnk | grep -EA3 "3D|VGA"   If you have nvidia driver installed turn of secure boot please.

The output of lspci -nnk | grep -EA3 "3D|VGA" is provided in the edit of the original question, secure boot is also disabled

my last have you install any nvidia driver (through apt or as run file)? If so dkms status please.

the nvidia drivers are installed via apt not as run file. The output of dkms status is in the edit of the original question

I'm sorry maybe this driver is to new for your card. Out of knowledge on my side.
